# Parallel Reduction does not work correctly

Tags: kernel, opencl, reduction

I have the following parallel kernel reduction written on OpenCL. I just want to sum all the values from the `BlockSum` array. While using the `work_group_reduce_add(BlockSum[GetIndex]);` it works perfectly right, using the optimized code I read from https://www.fz-juelich.de/SharedDocs/Downloads/IAS/JSC/EN/slides/opencl/opencl-05-reduction.pdf?__blob=publicationFile (Slide 11) does not work correctly. What seems to be the error here? The global_work_size is set to {16,16} as well as the local_work_size (meaning 256 threads in total for each workgroup). In the case of the `work_group_reduce_add` I get 255 which is correct but with the optimized code I get 0

```
__kernel void Reduction()
{
        unsigned char GetThreadX = get_local_id(0); //it takes values from 0..15
        unsigned char GetThreadY = get_local_id(1); //it takes values from 0..15
        unsigned char GetGroup   = get_local_size(0); //16
        unsigned short  BlockSum[256];      
        int SumOfAll= 0;            
        
        unsigned short GetIndex = GetThreadX + (GetGroup * GetThreadY); // takes values 0..255, group=16        
        
        BlockSum[GetIndex] = 1;             
        barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);       
        
        SumOfAll= work_group_reduce_add(BlockSum[GetIndex]); //works great  
        
        // BUT CODE BELOW DOES NOT SUM CORRECTLY
        /*
        for(unsigned short stride=128; stride>1; stride >>= 1) {
            
            if(GetIndex < stride)
                BlockSum[GetIndex] += BlockSum[GetIndex + stride];          
            barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);           
        }               
        if(GetIndex==0)             
            SumOfAll = BlockSum[0] + BlockSum[1];       
        barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);
        */
        printf("SumOfAll=%d\n",SumOfAll);
}
```

Comment: `unsigned char GetThreadX = get_local_id(0);` why `char` and not `int` ?

Comment: @AndreasHadjigeorgiou Cos get_local_id(0) get values from 0..15

Comment: Hmm I didn't know you could do that, interesting!!!

Comment: @AndreasHadjigeorgiou Why wasting precious private memory of the GPU for nothing?

Comment: Yes, this is a good point! Registers are indeed precious.

Comment: What is the largest value you can store for `unsigned char`? is it `2^8 - 1 = 255` ?

Comment: @AndreasHadjigeorgiou 2^8 which is a range from 0...255 (256 in total)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok problem fixed. The `BlockSum[256];` was not declared as `__local` but as private memory (silently without the `__local` Address Space Qualifier) which means that every thread (or core) had its own copy of these data, but the optimized reduction code was looking for ****shared* local memory*** data among threads, to sum up the values. Also the variable `int SumOfAll;` should also be declared as `__local` with initialization or `private` in my case without any initialization before. You choose.

So the working kernel is now looking like this.

*I hope this type of error will help someone that is not cautious like myself.*

```
__kernel void Reduction()
{
        unsigned char GetThreadX = get_local_id(0); //it takes values from 0..15
        unsigned char GetThreadY = get_local_id(1); //it takes values from 0..15
        unsigned char GetGroup   = get_local_size(0); //16

        //*********************************************************
        //below was the offending code and the root of the problem 
        //**********************************************************
        __local unsigned short  BlockSum[256];      
        int SumOfAll;           
        //**********************************************************
        
        unsigned short GetIndex = GetThreadX + (GetGroup * GetThreadY); // takes values 0..255, group=16        
        
        BlockSum[GetIndex] = 1;             
        barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);       
        
        //SumOfAll = work_group_reduce_add(BlockSum[GetIndex]); 
        
        // OPTIMIZED CODE BELOW NOW SUM UP CORRECTLY
        
        for(unsigned short stride=128; stride>1; stride >>= 1) {
            
            if(GetIndex < stride)
                BlockSum[GetIndex] += BlockSum[GetIndex + stride];          
            barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);           
        }               
        if(GetIndex==0)             
            SumOfAll = BlockSum[0] + BlockSum[1];       
        barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);
        
        printf("SumOfAll=%d\n",SumOfAll);
        


        
    
}
```